# how to prove transitive relation for this one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$R=\{(x,y) \mid 3 |(x-y^2) \}$ while R is relation on set A=$\mathbb{Z}$

I need to check if it's reflective , symmetric , transitive .

I figured already that it's not reflective or symmetric with (2,1) or (10,2),(2,10)

and I don't how to check if it's transitive or not.

I think we need to prove that, we have $(x,y), (y,c)$ thus $(x,c) $ then $3|(x-y^2)  = 0$ and
3|$(y-c^2) = 0$ but $3|(x-c^2) \neq  0$

Comment: Show: if $(y-c^2)\bmod 3=0,$ then $(y^2-c^2)\bmod 3=0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How does that help/

Comment: It’s a hint, not an answer.

Comment: $(x,c)  \mapsto 3|(x-y^2)$ is nonsense.

Comment: @WilliamElliot i didnt mean it directly

Comment: Unacceptable excuse @LightLamps.  State what you mean and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Edited

Comment: Note  $c^2 \equiv -1\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ is not possible.  So if you have $x \equiv y^2\pmod 3$ and $y \equiv z^2\pmod 3$ you must have $y \equiv 0,1$ and $x \equiv 0,1$.

Comment: @LightLamps  Useless edit.  Wake up, an ordered pair is not a statement.

Comment: @WilliamElliot How about you chill down? lol

Comment: @LightLamps needs to learn how to write coherent math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $3|x-y^2$ and $3|y-z^2$ does it follow that $3|x-z^2$?

$3|x-y^2\implies z\equiv y^2 \pmod 3$ and $3|y-z^2\implies y\equiv z^2 \pmod 3$.

So if $x\equiv y^2$ and $y\equiv z^2$ then $x \equiv z^4\equiv \pmod 3$.

Must it follow that $z^4 \equiv z^2 \pmod 3$?

If $z\equiv 0$ then $z^2 \equiv z^4 \pmod 3$ and, yes,  $x\equiv y^2\pmod 3$ and $y\equiv 0^2\pmod 3\implies x\equiv 0\equiv z^2 \pmod 3$.

If $z \equiv \pm 1$ then $1\equiv z^2\equiv z^4 \pmod 3$ and yes $x\equiv y^2 \pmod 3$ and $y\equiv (\pm 1)^2 \equiv 1\pmod 3 \implies y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and so $x\equiv y^2 \equiv 1\equiv z^2 \pmod 3$.

So yes, it is transitive.

......

Alternatively.  If $3|x-y^2$ then we have $x-y^2 = 3k$ for some $k$.  And $3|y-z^2$ then we have $y-z^2 = 3j$ for some $j$.  So $y=3j-z^2$.

So $x-y^2 = x-(9j^2 - 6jz^2 + z^4)= 3k$

So $x-z^2 = 3k + 9j^2 - (6j+1)z^2 + z^4=$

$3(k + 3j^2 -2jz^2) +z^4-z^2$.

so $3|x-z^2$ if and only if $z^4-z^2 = z^2(z^2 - 1)=z^2(z+1)(z-1)$ is divisible by $3$.

But either $z, z+1$ or $z-1$ must be divisible by $3$ as they are three consectutive integers and *one* of them must be divisible by $3$.

So $3|z^2(z+1)(z-1)$.

Comment: what does ≡ stand for

Comment: It means "is equivalent to".  I assume you are familiar with modular arithmetic.  $a \equiv b \pmod n$ means that $n|a-b$ or equivalently that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder with divided by $n$.  Basic modular arithmetic is $a\equiv a'\pmod n$ and $b\equiv b'\pmod n$ implies $a+b \equiv a' + b'\pmod n; ab \equiv a'b'\pmod n$ and $a^k\equiv a'^k\pmod n$.